# Connecting Apache Drill with Snowflake DB

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-drill

I am trying to connect Apache Drill to query Snowflake data warehouse. I was able to successfully create a snowflake storage plugin in Drill web UI with JSON structure as below. But I am not able to either explore the tables in the schema in the explorer nor query the tables. I am using Snowflake JDBC driver from their site: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#examples

What am I doing wrong?

```
{
 "type": "jdbc",
 "driver": "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver",
  "url": "jdbc:snowflake://accountname.snowflakecomputing.com/? 
    warehouse=wh&db=test_db&schema=test_schema",
  "username": "user",
  "password": "pwd",
  "caseInsensitiveTableNames": false,
  "enabled": true
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to connect to snowflake DB and Query the table:

My Storage Plugin config is:

```
{
  "name" : "snowflake",
  "config" : {
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "driver" : "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver",
    "url" : "jdbc:snowflake://Account.eu-central-1.snowflakecomputing.com/?warehouse=Compute_WH&db=Anshul_DB&schema=Anshul_SC",
    "username" : “User",
    "password" : “Password",
    "caseInsensitiveTableNames" : false,
    "enabled" : true
  }
}
```

Once I set up the Storage Plugin I used the command 
Show databases and I am able to see Snowflake Databases.
Then used to USE command to set Default Schema to my snowflake Schama
Use snowflake_anshulsc
Then tried running the command:
Show tables in snowflake.anshul_sc
Go the Table name

Then To query the table use the below command;

```
select * from snowflake.anshul_sc.T1
```

Comment: Thanks @Anshul Thakur. I realized my config did not have any problems. I was using drill explorer UI and I was not able to expand the snowflake entry in the browser of drill explorer. Now after checking in command line, it works fine